# Populate label with date from datepicker

Tags: jquery

I am am trying to test populating a label with a date selected in a jquery date picker. What I am getting on the label is [OBJECT][OBJECT]. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Calculate Days", "Calendar", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <h2>Enter The Number Of Days To Display</h2>

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DaysToBeViewed)

        <label id="dateSelected"></label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="daysAdded()" />
    }

    <script type="text/javascript">


        var dateSelected = $("#date").datepicker("getDate");

        function daysAdded(addDaysEntered, dateSelected) {

            var oneDAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
            var addDaysEnteredMiliSec = addDaysEntered.getTime()
            var DateMiliSec = Date.getTime()
            var datesAddedmiliSec = Math.abs(addDaysEnteredMiliSec + DateMiliSec)
            return Math.round(datesAddedmiliSec / oneDay)
        }
     </script>

     <script>
        document.getElementById('dateSelected').innerHTML = dateSelected;
     </script>

    <script>

        $(function () {
            $('#Date').datepicker();

        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated on http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate, the getDate() method returns the current date for the datepicker or null if no date has been selected. The type of object returned is a Date object, not a string.

[The Date type is a JavaScript object that represents a single moment in time. Date objects are instantiated using their constructor function, which by default creates an object that represents the current date and time.](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Date)

You need to convert the Date object to a string. For example:

```
var dateSelected = $("#date").datepicker("getDate").toString();
```

The available Date Object Methods are covered on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp.

Comment: I made that change and when I run in debug, I get the message that the break point will not be hit, so I am missing something somewhere else too.